# Programm giving Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: LocalHost:

Tags: java, android, sockets, localhost

I am trying to connect socket for communication java with android using this example:https://github.com/user370305/Android-USB-Communication

I have run a command from readMe file:
   adb forward tcp:38300 tcp:38300

When I try to run Java code from an example I get the error: `Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: LocalHost`. The full stacktrace is

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2675)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:3150)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:859)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:355)
    at USBClient.main(USBClient.java:24)
```

Can you say what I am doing wrong?

When I tried: 
   netstat -ano | findstr :38300

TCP    127.0.0.1:38300        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       15540

Is it Ok?

Comment: The exception handling in that Java code is no good. At least modify it to print the exception stacktrace.

Comment: I have modified it so stacktrace gives: java.io.EOFException
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2675)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:3150)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:859)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:355)
 at USBClient.main(USBClient.java:24)'